# Prove power method is not guaranteed to converge on non-diagonalizable matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

I see papers like this one ([https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/w~csip/tirgul2.pdf](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/w%7Ecsip/tirgul2.pdf)) claim that the Power Method for calculating dominant eigenvalue/eigenvector is NOT guaranteed to converge if the matrix is non-diagonalizable.

I'm stuck on how to prove this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This could be a very nice question but you must provide more details. Can you write down this Power Method algorithm?

Comment: True but strange claim. The power method is not guaranteed to converge, regardless of whether the matrix is diagonalisable or non-diagonalisable.